# How to transfer 3000+ items from iPhone hidden album to mac?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, photos

I have about 3700 items in my iPhone hidden album. How can I transfer all of them from my iPhone to my MacBook? They are all backed up on iCloud. If I try to download them on my Mac from iCloud, it only does so in batches of 500 items. If I try to copy-paste using USB, it still only does 1000 items at a time. How can I transfer all 3700 items at once?

Comment: You can try the macOS or Windows app [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) which has a free trial. If it works for you, purchase the software and support a great developer. It has successfully extracted many photo, video, music files and other data otherwise not available through the Apple UI. _No ties, financial or otherwise, with Macroplant LLC._